# Django ManyToManyField Validators

Tags: django, django-models

What's the best solution to apply following requirement?

In my model I have 2 **manytomany fields** (team1 and team2) which contains both a list of players.
**If a player is in team1 he cannot be also in team2**. How can I implement this logic?

First idea is to use validators, but they are not supported by manytomanyfield as in the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), so i'm humbling ask your support for a better solution please.

As of now not a single view expose a POST to create matches and only admin via django admin should be able to create matches.

here the Model

```
class Match(models.Model):

    date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=False)
    team1=models.ManyToManyField(Player,related_name='team_1')
    team2=models.ManyToManyField(Player,related_name='team_2')
    score_team1=models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
        )
    score_team2=models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to work with one `ManyToManyField`, and add a custom junction table that determines what field is used, like:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player, through='MatchPlay', related_name='matches'
    )
    score_team1 = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    score_team2 = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

    @property
    def players_team_1(self):
        return self.players.filter(plays__team=False)

    @property
    def players_team_2(self):
        return self.players.filter(plays__team=True)


class MatchPlay(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plays'
    )
    player = models.ForeignKey(
        Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plays'
    )
    team = models.BooleanField()  # 0/1

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('match', 'player'), name='player_only_plays_on_one_team'
            )
        ]
```

Here we even enforce this by the modeling and through a `UniqueConstraint` that you can not add the same player a second time, so a `Player` will definitely play for one team, which team depends on the `BooleanField` that is `False` for the first team, and `True` for the second team.

It can also make the queries for some cases easier, like finding out all `Match`es that a `Player` played in, regardless whether that was as first or second team.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save function and check if the player is already assigned to a team. This is the first approach that I've found:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.pk:
        # Only execute this logic if the Match instance is being created (not updated)
        players_in_team1 = self.team1.all()
        players_in_team2 = self.team2.all()

        for player in players_in_team1:
            if player not in players_in_team2:
                self.team2.add(player)
                break

        for player in players_in_team2:
            if player not in players_in_team1:
                self.team1.add(player)
                break
    else:
        team1_players = self.team1.all()
        team2_players = self.team2.all()
        all_players = list(team1_players) + list(team2_players)

        if len(set(all_players)) != len(all_players):
            raise ValueError("Each player must be unique across both teams.")
    super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Likely that will not work since at the time of saving, the m2m's are not *yet* populated: in order to do that, it first saves the `Match`, and `Player`s (if these are created), and then populates the through model (and table) on m2ms, the `.save()` of the `Match` and `Player` is then already saved, so it can not see what the m2ms contains.

Comment: Certainly, we can condense the logic to make it more concise.

Comment: yes, you could probably do this in a `ModelForm`, that thus has access to the m2m fields *before* saving it, and thus has the "full picture", but not in the `.save()` method of the models over which an m2m spans.